# IBM JDK 7 is missing jstatd. Not able to monitor Java application running on AIX using VisualVM.

Tags: performance-testing, aix, visualvm, jvisualvm, ibm-was

I have an enterprise application running on AIX 7 and have installed both IBM JDK 6 and 7 in the server. As per the VisualVM documentation, we need to start the **jstatd** daemon on the server. This utility is however missing in IBM JDKs. 
How can I use **VisualVM** to monitor application running on AIX?
Is there any other way to monitor application running on AIX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use JMX connector. Specify the following JVM properties:

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333  
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
```

and use [JMX connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html)